# How to add an index of an ArrayList to the same Arraylist Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to add the an index of a 2 dimensional ArrayList to the same ArrayList.
Code should be something like the following but index numbers and the same ArrayList must be involved:

```
ArrayList<String> a[0] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
ArrayList<String> a[1] = a[0];
```

Of course this code won't work.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Post an example of your desired output.

Comment: a(0) = A, B, C --- a(1) = A, B, C must be done through index numbers or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[i]` is used to access and assign array elements.

Assuming a is declared as :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

You assign the inner lists with :

```
a.set(0,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
a.set(1,a.get(0));
```

Note that this code will work only if `a`'s size is at least 2 (i.e. it already has values for indices 0 and 1). If `a` is empty, you should use :

```
a.add (new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
a.add (a.get(0));
```

Comment: ArrayList is backed by an array and when you instantiate with `new ArrayList<>()`, it creates an array of size 0 and when you do set with index it would give you IOOBE.

Comment: @SMA That's true. That's why I gave two options. The first option only works if the ArrayList already contains elements at the 0 and 1 indices.

Comment: @Otag `a.get(1).get(2)`

Comment: During my debugging efforts debugger gives a.add(a.get(donsay - 1)); the following exception =>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1           <-------->donsay is the integer variable for looping purposes...Any ideas on what is going on??

Comment: @Otag this means that a contains just one element,  whose index is 0, but you are trying to access an element at index 1.

Comment: @Eran Hello, index(0) is full checked it has 8 items.. This code supposed to copy index(0) to index(1). If this code doesn't do it have you any idea what will??. Your answers are much appreciated...

Comment: @Otag I would check if perhaps you have multiple `a` variables and you are adding two elements to one of them while trying to access the second element of the other.

Comment: @Eran checked. That is not the issue. I even tried a.add(a.get(0)); And I know a(0) is full. If I break out of the code at index 0 the code works.

Comment: @Eran the code doesn't seem to work or there is catch to it.

Comment: @Eran...The code works. There is something wrong with the variable. Thank you again...

Comment: @Eran The thing is that it is not accepting a variable as an index value. Any way around that you can think of???....

Comment: @Otag What do you mean by that? Can you show a relevant code sample?

Comment: wp.add(wp.get(donsay-1));
        bp.add(bp.get(donsay-1));
        wr.add(wr.get(donsay-1));
        br.add(br.get(donsay-1)); 
        wn.add(wn.get(donsay-1)); ---- donsay is equal to 1

Comment: @Otag The question is where `donsay` is declared (is it a local variable, instance variable?), where it is initialized and where these `add` methods are called. I need more context.

Comment: ---- donsay is equal to 1 and it gives the following exception ---- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

Comment: Give me your secondary e-mail and I'll send the whole code. My e-mail askuralbilisim@gmail.com. Send a PM here if you wish...

Comment: @Otag But what line of code throws that exception? The `.get(donsay-1)` shouldn't throw that exception if `donsay` is 1. They can only throw it if `donsay` is 2.

Comment: wp.add(wp.get(donsay-1)); exception at  the beginning of this code.

Comment: Donsay gets its value from a parameter sent to the method in the class. It is 0. But before the code it is incremented as=> donsay = param2;
        donsay++;
It is declared as => int donsay;

Comment: if (donsay==0) {
    //a.add (new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    wp.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2")));
    bp.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7")));
    wr.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a1", "h1")));
    br.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a8", "h8")));
    wn.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("b1", "g1")));
    bn.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("b8", "g8")));
    wb.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("c1", "f1")));
    ..etc..

Comment: else {
    wp.add(wp.get(donsay - 1));
    bp.add(bp.get(donsay - 1));
    wr.add(wr.get(donsay - 1));
    br.add(br.get(donsay - 1));
    wn.add(wn.get(donsay - 1));
    bn.add(bn.get(donsay - 1));
    wb.add(wb.get(donsay - 1));
... etc.